# How can I specify a default color for a react-native-elements button?

Tags: react-native

Right now I am using the **[react-native-elements](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-elements)** component library for my app. Specifically I am using their Button component, which has a default color of grey applied to it.

[image]

How can I set a custom default color for these buttons without having to pass in style props every time?

Is there a simple function/method I can call, or do I have to look at creating a custom component to wrap it? I would prefer the former.

Comment: You would need to create a custom component.

Comment: ^  Plain wrong. Custom styles and themes can be defined as answered below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went ahead and made a wrapper class for now. If someone finds out how to do it the other way please post.

To do this I did the following

-Imported the **Button** class from **react-native-elements**

```
import {Button} from 'react-native-elements'
```

-Created a **Component** class where I passed along all the same props I send to the original button from react-native-elements.

```
class ButtonCustom extends Component{    
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    }
    render(){
      return (
        <Button 
        {...this.props} 
        backgroundColor={this.props.backgroundColor|| 'blue' } /> 
        //this allows me to override that backgroundColor if i need to
      )
    }  
}
```

-Exported it as a module for easy reuse

```
module.exports = ButtonCustom;
```

Whenever I need it I simply import and use it. I at least don't need to set the styling each time and if I need to I can make global changes.

```
<ButtonCustom
          title="Blue Automatically"
          />
```

Comment: In the current version ("react-native-elements": "^1.1.0"), the backgroundColor is now defined as follows: <Button title={'Submit'} buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: 'red'}} />

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question, but since i found this post, i will leave this answer here for others to see.

react-native-elements supports theming since [Oct 2018](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/pull/1454). As per the [documentation](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/customization.html#theming) you can use a theme provider in your RN application and override the library's default colors by doing something like this:

```
import { ThemeProvider } from 'react-native-elements';

const theme = {
  colors: {
    primary: 'pink',
  }
}

....
....

render(){
  ...
  return(
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme} >
         <App/>
      </ThemeProvider>
   )
}
```

The above example will change the primary color for all your components. By applying the same logic, you can change the background color only for button elements. You can also use theming for other customizations, like default component properties etc. For more information, check out the docs

Comment: if you have `export default function App()` and some simple `View` in it just wrap the `View` with the `ThemeProvider` like `<ThemeProvider theme={theme}><View ...</View></ThemeProvider>` :-)

Comment: Do we have other way except `react-native-element`?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher not sure what you mean by that, but you can always build your own custom button component if you don't want to use a library.

Answer (score 5):

**On the contrary, if someone wants to change color of specific components**

You can use the buttonStyle prop of the Button component. In it, you can set styles as normal like backgroundColor and color

```
  import {Button} from 'react-native-elements'

  <Button
      buttonStyle={{
         backgroundColor: "red"
      }}

      containerStyle={{
         marginTop: 12,
         width: "40%"
      }}

      title="Cancel"
   />
```

Check official docs: https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html#buttonstyle

Answer (score 1):

According to their docs, you can pass a `backgroundColor` property as a string instead of having to pass it through `style`. Here is an example:

```
<Button
  backgroundColor={'red'}
  large
  iconRight
  icon={{name: 'code'}}
  title='LARGE WITH RIGHT ICON' 
/>
```

But if you're going to use the same exact button in multiple places, then you might want to just create your own component and wrap it.

More info: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-elements#buttons

Comment: yeah i wanted to avoid the per button color thing, so that i could even update all in one place. i will look into the customizing of it. thanks

Comment: In the current version ("react-native-elements": "^1.1.0"), the backgroundColor is now defined as follows: <Button title={'Submit'} buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: 'red'}} />